# Can I get the PID of a program I execute in another program?

Tags: c, exec, pid

If I execute an `exec` into a main process of a program, can I somehow get the PID (Process ID) of the process executed by the `exec` in order to send interruptions / signals towards it later on?

Comment: Maybe `execl("child", ..., getpid(), ...);` and the `child` somehow uses the parent pid to notify about its own *process id*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes on linux you can fork a child process and get is PID like in [https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/)

```
#include <stdio.h>

    
int main( void ) {
    char *argv[3] = {"Command-line", ".", NULL};

    int pid = fork();

    if ( pid == 0 ) {
        execvp( "find", argv );
    }

    /* Put the parent to sleep for 2 seconds--let the child finished executing */
    wait( 2 );

    printf( "Finished executing the parent process\n"
            " - the child won't get here--you will only see this once\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

source :   [https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edwharder/icsrts/Tutorials/fork_exec/)

`getpid()` is also in this link